# Why does google spanner use both two phase commit and paxos?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I'm reading a paper for Google spanner https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/spanner-osdi2012.pdf
and one thing that's not clear to me is the choice for implementing both two phase commit and Paxos. The paper states that when a transaction involves multiple Paxos groups, two phase commit is used to complete the transaction. My question is why not implementing two phase commit over those Paxos groups instead of implementing Paxos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find more details and the answer of your question in the [Spanner, TrueTime &
The CAP Theorem](https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/45855.pdf) document in the "What happens during a Partition" paragraph.

> To understand partitions, we need to know a little bit more about how Spanner works. As with most ACID
>   databases, Spanner uses two-phase commit (2PC) and strict two-phase locking to ensure isolation and
>   strong consistency. 2PC has been called the “anti-availability” protocol [Hel16] because all members must
>   be up for it to work. Spanner mitigates this by having each member be a Paxos group, thus ensuring each
>   2PC “member” is highly available even if some of its Paxos participants are down. Data is divided into
>   groups that form the basic unit of placement and replication.

Basically Spanner, as most ACID databases, it uses the 2PC ( two phase commit ), and it uses Paxos groups to mitigate the "anti-availability" shortcoming.

Comment: Does this mean that in worst case (If all replicas are down for a split), Spanner could still become inconsistent ?

Answer (score 5):

At the highest level of abstraction, Spanner is a database that shards data across many sets of Paxos state machines in datacenters spread all over the world.

Replication is used for global availability and geographic locality; clients
automatically failover between replicas. Spanner automatically reshards data across machines as the amount of data or the number of servers changes, and it automatically migrates data across machines (even across datacenters) to balance load and in repsonse to failures.

To support replication, each spanserver implements a single Paxos state machine on top of each tablet. (An early Spanner incarnation supported multiple Paxos state machines per tablet, which allowed for more flexible replication configurations. The complexity of that design led us to abandon it.)  Each state machine stores its metadata and log in its corresponding tablet. Our Paxos implementation supports long-lived leaders with time-based leader leases, whose length defaults to 10 seconds. The current Spanner implementation logs every Paxos write twice: once in the tablet’s log, and once in the Paxos log. This choice was made out of expediency, and we are likely to remedy this eventually.

Our implementation of Paxos is pipelined, so as to improve Spanner’s throughput in the presence of WAN latencies. By “pipelined,” we mean Lamport’s “multi-decree parliament”, which both amortizes the cost of electing a leader across multiple decrees and allows for concurrent voting on different decrees. It is important to note that although decrees may be approved out of order, the decrees are applied in order.

The Paxos state machines are used to implement a consistently replicated bag of mappings. The key-value mapping state of each replica is stored in its corresponding tablet. Writes must initiate the Paxos protocol at the leader; reads access state directly from the underlying tablet at any replica that is sufficiently up-to-date. The set of replicas is collectively a Paxos group.

In both Bigtable and Spanner, we designed for long-lived transactions (for example, for report generation, which might take on the
order of minutes), which perform poorly under optimistic concurrency control in the presence of conflicts. Operations that require synchronization, such as transactional reads, acquire locks in the lock table; other operations bypass the lock table. The state
of the lock table is mostly volatile (i.e., not replicated via Paxos): we explain the details
further in Section 4.2.1.(Note that having a long-lived Paxos leader is critical
to efficiently managing the lock table.)

At every replica that is a leader, each spanserver also implements a transaction manager to support distributed transactions. The transaction manager is used to implement a participant leader; the other replicas in the group will be referred to as participant slaves. If a transaction involves only one Paxos group (as is the case for most transactions), it can bypass the transaction manager, since the lock table and Paxos together provide transactionality. If a transaction involves more than one Paxos group, those groups’ leaders coordinate to perform two-phase commit. One of the participant groups is chosen as the coordinator: the participant leader of that group will be referred to as the coordinator leader, and the slaves of that group as coordinator slaves. The state of each transaction manager is stored in the underlying Paxos group (and therefore is replicated).

Source material -

[Google’s Globally Distributed Database](https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/65b514eda12d025585183a641b5a9e096a3c4be5.pdf)

[Spanner, TrueTime & The CAP Theorem](https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/45855.pdf)

[Life of Cloud Spanner Reads & Writes](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/whitepapers/life-of-reads-and-writes)

[Spanner vs. Calvin: Distributed Consistency at Scale](https://fauna.com/blog/distributed-consistency-at-scale-spanner-vs-calvin)

[GOOGLE SPANNER: BEGINNING OF THE END OF THE NOSQL WORLD?](https://wp.sigmod.org/?p=2153)